# python - set function return statement to string

Tags: python, string, int, concatenation

Complete newbie to python, only really looked at it this morning. My question is when defining a function how can I set the "return(variable)" statement as a string. I assumed the below would be the correct method however the syntax is incorrect, struggling to find resources online for this particular way of converting the data type. The result is forming as follows:

"The result is:

286"

By converting it to a string it should form:
"The result is: 286"

Here is what I thought would work:

```
def fnc2(a,b,c):
total=(a+b)*c
print("the result is: ") + str(return(total));
```

Comment: return is a statement.  at the end just do `return total`

Comment: Do you want to return the result to the caller of the function or do you want to output it on the console (a.k.a. "print" it, although this won't result in a paper print-out) or both or something else?

Comment: You should really have researched defining functions first instead of asking here.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. Python spacing matters, so don't forget to indent!
2. Check your `print` [syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). Everything you're printing should be inside the parens

One form of correct syntax would be:

```
def fnc2(a, b, c):
    total = (a + b) * c
    print("The result is: " + str(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly indent the code to function, also the return statement ends the function.

```
def fnc2(a,b,c):
    total=(a+b)*c
    return str(total)

print("The result is: " + fnc2(10, 20, 30))
```

Also, if you want to convert the result of your computation to a string for printing only, you should not return a string from your function, but rather do the conversion when you want to print the result.

```
def fnc2(a,b,c):
    total=(a+b)*c
    return total

print("The result is: " + str(fnc2(10, 20, 30)))
```